# Url with query string returns a 404 with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, encode

I have some buttons which filter content:

```
http://www.example.com/?page_id=123&ajax=3&content1
```

This works fine, but when I view the console, I see this being return as an error:

```
http://www.example.com/?page_id=123%3Fajax%3D3&content1
```

How I created the Url

```
<?php 
$filterLink = get_the_permalink();
$filterLink .='&ajax=3&';
$filterLink .= $term->slug;
?>
```

How do I make this encode properly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code where you generate that url?

Comment: Sure thing. Updated.

Comment: And now the javascript (ajax) part ;-)